# Adjusting Velocity Of Object

Tags: python, game-engine

So I'm making a small game on Blender Game Engine and its racing. What i want is so that when a player presses w the car starts moving and slowly gains velocity. I know about the controller's that make an object move but i want to know how to make it BUILD speed as it progresses.(the reason i tagged this as python is because i am assuming this will take some python. Do i use Python for this)?

Comment: No python needed whatsoever.

Comment: How the  ziff is this a duplicate. the link given takes me to a question asking a completely different thing.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it doesn't require python. It requires the ... servo motion actuator:
[image]
Use the LinearVelocity to set the maximum speed, and the force limits to set the maximum acceleration.

For anything more complex than this, yes, you will need python.